# Activity indicator not hiding when webpage is loaded

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview

The activity indicator isn't hiding when the web page has finished loading. 
Here is my

**.h file**

```
@interface PropertyViewController : UIViewController{

    IBOutlet UIWebView *propertyNexusHome;
    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *wheel;
    NSTimer *timer;
}
```

**.m file**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [property loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                         [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];
    [property addSubview:wheel];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0)
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(loading)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
-(void)loading {
    if (!property.loading)
        [wheel stopAnimating];

    else
        [wheel startAnimating];

}

@end
```

Im not sure why its not disappearing, how ever it does stop spinning when the page has loaded.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you are doing is not right. Add the `UIActivityIndicator` as soon as loading starts, get it from the `UIWebView` delegate. And stop it when loading finished or failed with error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another option would be to set `[wheel setHidesWhenStopped:YES]` when you create the Activity Indicator.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add:

```
wheel.hidden = YES;
```

when it stops animating